# Reverse filtering - Data exclusion

Tags: filter, big-data

Currently, we are building a big data web app, which consists of a data table and a big number of filters

One of the **user requirements is the exclusion of some data.** Therefore, I have added a reverse option as it appears in the current image.

[image: first solution]

I am wondering if there is a common practice for handling this issue, any research happened before, a better way to handle this requirement.

What of this solutions seems more intuitive?

[image: possible solutions according to the answers]

Comment: All makes sense, but reverse...? Does that mean what ever is selected will be unselected? This is a tad bit confusing.

Comment: @Majo0od that is the idea. Imagine that the user wants to see all results except numbers 100-200. How would you do it?

Comment: You need an option to `exclude` specified items. It is fairly common in reporting apps. Usually takes the form of `and` / `or` / `not`. Dig around a bit and you'll find precedents. What you've proposed is definitely *not* standard.

Comment: Just curious - Why can't the user select all and then deselect the ones that are not needed? Select All - is just one extra step for the user, and any ways - he/she has to go and select the ones to exclude. It could be as well done as a deselect operation. Unless I misunderstood the situation. Also, I think for batch selection/deselection in data like this, you could think of adding hierarchies/nesting in the models/data, and complement it with a search UI to easily get to the model or series one is looking at.

Comment: @AmitJain Thank you! After considering all the options, I think that this is the clearest solution possible. Could you write it as an answer instead, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Happy it helps. Answer added with some improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per one of your comments, the use case is that of "**Selecting All models except few**" For doing the same,

1) The user can 'Select All' and then deselect the ones that are not needed. Select All - is just one extra step for the user, and any ways - he/she has to go and select the ones to exclude (in the exclude UI you have proposed). It could be as well done as a deselect operation.

2) Also, I think for batch selection/deselection in data like this, you could think of adding hierarchies/nesting in the models/data, and complement it with a search UI to easily get to the model or series one is looking at. Attaching a close example I could find for nested data groups.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly, what you want is the filter to be inclusive or exclusive. You could use a dropdown which has both options:

- Include
- Exclude

With the default to be the most used one (include I presume). The phrasing could adapt better to your scenario but the idea is *"Include results from the selected filters only"*, *"Exclude results from the selected filters"*.

Comment: This is a good answer. Would it be possible to demonstrate it? I don't know how it would be presented when the results would be excluded.

Comment: @DimitraMiha Thanks :) I would either do a dropdown with the two options clearly indicated (maybe "Search in the following printers"/"Exclude the following printers from the search results"). Or possibly only a checkbox for the exclude option.